# Change value of passed variable in Javascript without return?

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

I have the function *change(x)* which takes an integer and changes its value

```
function change(x) {
   x=26;
}
```

Then I make a variable and I try to change its value

```
window.onload=function(){
   var a = 10;
   change(a);
   console.log(a);
}
```

*a* doesn't change as I would expect. Is it possible to achieve this behaviour in JavaScript in a simple way without using return? I would prefer to avoid objects and globals.

Here is my whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <script>
   function change(x) {
      x=26;
   }
   window.onload=function(){
      var a = 10;
      change(a);
      console.log(a);
   }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, `a = change(a);`

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript always passes arguments by value, so you can't do it as you originally written.

However, an object's value is a reference, so you could use an object.

However, that would be confusing for this use case. You should have that function return the transformed number.

Comment: The problem is that there is a callback function inside my "change" function, thus I cannot return the value. I get 'undefined' then.

Comment: @Pithikos You should use callback function.

Comment: "However, an object's value is a reference" You mean, a variable's value is a reference, which points to an object.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a variable by reference like that (or at all). What you *can* do is pass an object and modify its properties:

```
function change(obj) {
    obj.a = 4;
}

var obj = {a: 0};
change(obj);

// obj.a is "4" now
```

Answer (score -2):

I did this and it worked:

```
function change(x) {   
  x=26;  
  return x;  
}  
  window.onload=function(){  
  var a = 10;  
  console.log(change(a));  
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Adding a `console.log(a)` at the end of your `window.onload` function proves you wrong.