# Why is the value of b printed as 23 and not 46?

Tags: javascript

**My code:**

```
var a = 23;
var b = a;
a = 46;
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Why is the value of **b** printed as 23 and not as 46?

**Output :**

a=46, b=23,

Comment: `a` and `b` are different variables and are assigned different values.

Comment: See also [Explaining Value vs. Reference in Javascript](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0) and these related questions: [javascript variable reference/alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686990/javascript-variable-reference-alias), [Javascript equivalent of assign by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732589/javascript-equivalent-of-assign-by-reference), [Change value of passed variable in Javascript without return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728938/change-value-of-passed-variable-in-javascript-without-return).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript equivalent of assign by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732589/javascript-equivalent-of-assign-by-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `var b = a;` is executed, `b` does not "refer" to `a`. It becomes a number whose value is `a`'s value at this moment.

---

However, if you use an **Object**, the attribution will use the **reference** of `a`, and not its value:

```
a = { value: 23 };
b = a;
a.value = 46;

console.log(b);
```

```
// console
Object { value: 46 }
```

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript, Only Objects/Arrays are passed by reference and others are passed by value. As a and b hold integer values they are passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language/51523031#51523031). Primitives are passed by values and objects are passed by reference. As a and b are primitives, they are passed by values. And when a is changed that will not be reflected in b.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are giving a value of a, and that is 23. Then you are reassign a to be 46.

Answer (score 0):

in your code first you initialize **`a`** with value of **`23`** and then you assign value of **`a`** to **`b`**

```
       var a = 23;
       var b = a;
        a = 46;
     console.log(a);
     console.log(b);
```

then you update value of **`a`** but not assigning it to **`b`**

As in **`Java-Script`**  Only **Objects/Arrays** are passed by reference and others are passed by value. As **`a`** and **`b`** hold integer values they are passed by value.

so updating value of `a` did not result in change of `b` value ; if you assign value to b after updating value of a it would result in displaying value of `46` for both `a and b`

Answer (score 0):

assignment operator means you assign the value of right side to the value of left side so by this statement var b = a; b becomes 23 and once you change a it has no affect on value of b due to lexical scoping of js.